# How to use Scala to partition data into buckets for further processing

Tags: scala

I want to read in a csv log which has as it's first column a timestamp of form hh:mm:ss.  I would like to partition the entries into buckets, say hourly.  I'm curious what the best approach is that adheres to Scala's semantics, i.e., reading the file as a stream, parsing it (maybe by a match predicate?) and emitting the csv entries as tuples.

It's been a couple of years since I looked at Scala but this problem seems particularly well suited to the language.

log format example:
[time],[string],[int],[int],[int],[int],[string]

The last field in the input could be mapped to an emum in the output tuple but I'm not sure there's value in that.

I'd be happy with a general recipe that I could use, with suggestions for certain built-in functions that are well suited to the problem.

The overall goal is a map-reduce, where I want to count elements in a time window but those elements first need to be preprocessed by a regex replace, before sorting and counting.

I've tried to keep the problem abstract, so the problem can be approached as a pattern to follow.

Thanks.

Comment: whether the file is already sorted by that first column makes a big difference.

Comment: True enough.  The log ordering is by timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps as a first pass, a simple [groupBy](http://markusjais.com/the-groupby-method-from-scalas-collection-library/) would do the trick ?

```
logLines.groupBy(line => line.timestamp.hours)
```

Comment: This pattern might work but I was hoping for more insight into the conversion of the time field as presented in a log, so a string, into a partitionable type.  Do you suggest splitting the line into a tuple first and creating a timestamp field from the first element?

Comment: You could certainly do that. Perhaps apply a regexp on the HH:mm component ?

Answer (score 0):

Using the groupBy idiom, and some filtering, my solution looks like

```
val lines: Traversable[String] = source.getLines.map(_.trim).toTraversable
val events: List[String] = lines.filter(line => line.matches("[\\d]+:.*")).toList
val buckets: Map[String, List[String]] = events.groupBy { line => line.substring(0, line.indexOf(":")) }
```

This gives me 24 buckets, one for each hour.  Now I can process each bucket, perform the regex replace that I need to de-parameterize the URIs and finally map-reduce those to find the frequency each route has occurred.

Important note.  I learned that groupBy doesn't work as desired, without first creating a List from the Traversable stream.  Without that step, the end result is a single valued map for each hour.  Possibly not the most performant solution, since it requires all events to be loaded in memory before partitioning.  Is there a better solution that can partition a stream?  Perhaps something that adds events to a mutable Set as the stream is processed?